# Why is foreach over a results object not working?

Tags: php, object, foreach, yahoo-api

I realize there are quite a few questions of this nature, but I have not been able to solve my issue using the other posts, so I was hoping someone here may be able to help me out.

I have an object I'm getting back from Yahoo local search API. I have passed the results into `json_decode()` and saved the results to `$yahoo_json_decoded`. I can get data from the results using a for loop and doing the following:

```
echo 'Name: ' . $yahoo_json_decoded->ResultSet->Result[$i]->Title . '<br />' ;
```

But I can't seem to be able to make the foreach work:

```
foreach($yahoo_json_decoded->ResultSet as $res=>$variable)
{
    $listingID = $yahoo_json_decoded->ResultSet[$res]->id ;
    echo $listingID;
}
```

I could just loop the data and move on, but I really want to understand why the `foreach` isn't working.

Thanks (show mercy)

Kirk

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The literal difference between the two loops**

The `for` loop in your snippet iterates over the ***array*** `$yahoo_json_decoded->ResultSet->Result`, while the `foreach` loop iterates over the ***object*** `$yahoo_json_decoded->ResultSet`.

In other words, in the `for` loop you're iterating over the ***array elements*** as you expect, whereas in the `foreach` loop you are in fact iterating over the ***object properties***.

**A demonstration of the difference**

For example, given this object:

```
$json = json_encode(array('result'=>array('apple','orange','lemon')));
$obj  = json_decode($json);
```

consider the difference between this loop:

```
for ($i=0; $i < count($obj->result); $i++) :
    echo $i.' - '.$obj->result[$i].' ';
endfor;
```

and this loop:

```
foreach ($obj as $key=>$val) :
    echo $key.' - ';
    var_dump($val);
endforeach;
```

The output of the first loop will be:

```
0 - apple 1 - orange 2 - lemon
```

While the output of the second will be:

```
result - array(3) { [0]=> string(5) "apple" [1]=> string(6) "orange" [2]=> string(5) "lemon" }
```

### **[See the difference in action](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/608-zr4)**

Comment: Boaz, thank you for the detailed explanation. That made it much easier to understand what I was doing wrong.

Comment: Boaz, honestly I never even noticed that. I guess when you have your mind on other stuff, it's easy to miss things right in your face. Answer accepted.

Answer (score 5):

Based on `$yahoo_json_decoded->ResultSet->Result[$i]->Title` which you say works:

```
foreach($yahoo_json_decoded->ResultSet->Result as $index => $result)
{
   $listingID = $result->id ;
    echo $listingID;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

From what I understand, you should be doing

```
foreach($yahoo_json_decoded->ResultSet->Result as $key => $val) //(...)
```

Answer (score 2):

you're missing a layer of Data structure in your foreach loop

```
foreach($yahoo_json_decoded->ResultSet->Result as $res=>$variable)
{
   $listingID = $variable->id ;
    echo $listingID;
}
```

versus your for loop

```
for ($i = 0; $i <10; $i++)
$yahoo_json_decoded->ResultSet->Result[$i]->Title
```

thus

```
$i = $res
$variable = $yahoo_json_decoded->ResultSet->Result[$i]
```

Comment: Thanks David. I'm starting to get a better understanding now.